# They set a prisoner free / They let a prisoner free

Tags: grammar

Could you please explain for me why I cannot use "let" in this sentence ?

My friends said "They let a prisoner free" is wrong but I cannot understand why let is unacceptable in this sentence.

Comment: I don't think I would use either in connection with a prisoner. I think I would say *They released a prisoner*. That would be the most common way of saying it, at least in Britain, I would suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got the 'let' idiom right:

> They let a prisoner **go free**

is fine and idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

*Set free* is an [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+free), those two words together have a particular meaning.

*Let* and *free* can go together as well, but they wouldn't have the same meaning. E.g. They *let* the prisoner *free* his pet. Here, *the prisoner* is the subject of *free* and the object of *let*, whereas in the other sentence, *the prisoner* is the object of *set free*.

Comment: The first paragraph is fine. In the second, this is a different meaning of _free_, and does not illuminate the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would use either in connection with a prisoner. I think I would say: ***They released a prisoner***.

That would be the most common form in Britain, I would suggest.

We tend to 'let' dogs out of their kennels, and 'set' animals free generally. *Tarzan my lurcher goes berserk when he is set free*